Shortest path through an intermediate node
How to find the shortest path in a directed graph with non-negative edge costs, from source S to destination D, with the constraint to pass through an intermediate node A? And the path shall not traverse any nodes more than once?
We cannot simply find two shortest paths from S to A and A to D then combine them, because there might be common nodes in these two paths.
The solution I think of involves some sort of exhaustive search: To find every path (using say, BFS) from S to A with the total costs below an upper bound, then find the corresponding shortest path from A to D (excluding the visited nodes). Finally, take the path with minimum cost.
I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it.
Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

This problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-hard. Even more, just checking for existence of such path is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problem. Here I refer to The directed subgraph homeomorphism problem by Steven Fortune, John Hopcroft and James Wyllie.

The subgraph homeomorphism problem is to determine: if a pattern graph $P$ is
homeomorphic to a subgraph of an input graph $G$. The homeomorphism maps nodes
of $P$ to nodes of $G$ and arcs of $P$ to simple paths in $G$. The graphs $P$ and $G$ are either both directed or both undirected. The paths in $G$ corresponding to arcs in $P$ must be pairwise node-disjoint. The mapping of nodes in $P$ to nodes in $G$ may be specified or left arbitrary.


We consider the question, for fixed pattern graph $P$, ‘Given as input a graph $G$ with node-mapping specified, does $G$ contain a subgraph homeomorphic to $P$?‘. We refer to this as the fixed subgraph homeomorphism problem.


Let $C$ be the collection of all directed graphs with a distinguished node called the root possessing the property that either the root is the head of every arc or the root is the tail of every arc. Note that the root may be both the head and tail of some arcs and thus loops at the root are allowed. Equivalently, a graph is in $C$ if, when all loops at the root are deleted and multiple arcs between pairs of nodes are merged into single arcs, the resulting graph is a tree of height at most one.


Theorem 2. For each $P$ not in $C$ the fixed subgraph homeomorphism problem with pattern $P$ is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete.

In your problem $P$ is a tree $s \to a \to d$ of height $2$, so $P$ is not in $C$. There is mapping of the vertices $s$, $a$ and $d$ of $P$ to the vertices $S$, $A$ and $D$ of the graph $G$. Therefore checking the existence of such path is equivalent to the fixed subgraph homeomorphism problem for $P$ not in $C$, so the problem is $\mathrm{NP}$-complete.

Edit: This works only for undirected graphs
Let's add an artificial node $B$ and connect both $S$ and $D$ to $B$. The problem is equivalent to finding two vertex disjoint paths between $A$ and $B$, with minimum total distance. If you just need edge-disjoint paths, this is efficiently solved by Suurballe's algorithm. For vertex disjoint paths, apply the standard transformation, where you replace every vertex $v$ with an edge $v_1v_2$ with weight $0$, the incoming arcs of $v$ become incoming arcs of $v_1$ and the outcoming arcs of $v$ become outcoming arcs of $v_2$. You then search for edge-disjoint shortest paths.

Do you mean I artificially add another node B to the graph directly connected to S and D, assign the weight of both links to be zero, then run the node-disjoint algorithm from A to B with minimum total distance?

@温文家 Yes, I clarified and added some algorithmic details.

In the third step, I think you mean find the shortest path from B to A, right? But if I already negate the cost and simultaneously reverse the direction on the previous shortest path, wouldn't that the new shortest path is just the reverse the previous one? I notice that your method is a bit similar to the Suurballe's algorithm. By the way, can you also give a brief explanation on why your method works or provide a link to the resources (if any) ? Thank you very much!

No, from $A$ to $B$. Actually, you can just run Suurballe's algorithm, it is more efficient, I will update the answer

But with the setup, what we require is the minimum total cost of two node-disjoint paths e.g. 'from B to A ' and 'A back to B'. Suurballe's algorithm cannot be directly applied in this case because that is for two node-disjoint paths from A to B. Since we are talking about a directed graph, this makes a huge difference.

Indeed, I was thinking with undirected graphs when coming with this setup, the directed problem might be harder...
